# How to generate space?

Tags: space-expansion

Space is its own existing thing as is matter and energy. We can turn Matter into energy and we can harness energy for motion so... how can we generate space?
because if we could generate space, we could do so "faster" than space is collapsing toward the center of the earth by "gravity" and you would have an object which is forever falling toward the center of the earth an yet is not moving toward the ground.

Comment: "*Space is its own existing thing as is matter and energy*" - Could you explain a bit more this statement?

Comment: by the general relativity equations space is an equivalent formulation for the stress energy tensor.  " because if we could generate space, we could do so "faster" than space is collapsing toward the center of the earth " rockets do it, and airoplanes.

Answer (score 3):

Spacetime isn't a thing. Or to be more precise in the description provided by General Relativity spacetime is not a thing. Spacetime is a purely mathematical object. It is a combination of a manifold and a metric. The metric is related to the matter and energy distribution by the Einstein equation, but the manifold is just taken as a starting point.

So spacetime cannot be generated. The distance between points in spacetime can change, but this is simply a change in the metric and is caused by the matter and energy present.